# Error de convertir DropDownList a Int32

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

**intento ingresar un valor por medio de un formulario y me genera este error, podrían ayudarme por favor**

[image: Este es el error y]

**este es el formulario**

```
 <asp:Table id="Table1" runat="server" CellPadding="8" GridLines="Both" 
        BorderColor="white" Height="419px" Width="500px">

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell> Tipo de documento</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="tipo_doc" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="tipo_doc" DataValueField="tipo_doc"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GestorTICConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Sp_TipoDoc"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Número de documento</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="num_doc" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Apellidos</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell> <asp:TextBox ID="apellidos" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox> </asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Nombres</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="nombres" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>E-mail </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Telefono</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="telefono" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Dirección</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="direccion" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>

     <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Número de cuenta</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="cuenta_banco" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Estado</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="estado" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="tipo_estado" DataValueField="tipo_estado"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GestorTICConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Sp_TipoEstado"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:Table id="Table2" runat="server" CellPadding="8" GridLines="Both" 
        BorderColor="white" Height="418px" Width="500px">

     <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Vinculo</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="vinculo" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="tipo_vinculo" DataValueField="tipo_vinculo"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GestorTICConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Sp_TipoVin"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Fecha de ingreso</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox type="date" ID="fec_ingreso" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Fecha de retiro</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox type="date" ID="fec_retiro" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Empresa real</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="emreal" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" DataTextField="IDempresa" DataValueField="IDempresa"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GestorTICConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Sp_TipoEmpre"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell> Tipo de licencia</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="tipo_licencia" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent" DataTextField="nom_licencia" DataValueField="nom_licencia"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GestorTICConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Sp_TipoLicen"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Número de licencia</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="num_licencia" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

     <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Fecha de expedición</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox type="date" ID="fecha_exp" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

     <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Fecha de vencimiento</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox type="date" ID="fecha_ven" runat="server" Width="250px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>

    <br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div class="botones">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Insertar" Height="35px"
            Width="125px" />
```

**Y este es mi procedimiento de Sql**

```
USE [GestorTIC]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_TipoDoc]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT Conductores.IDTdocumento, Conductores.tipo_doc FROM TipoDocumento AS Conductores
INNER JOIN  TipoDocumento AS TipoDocumento ON
Conductores.tipo_doc = TipoDocumento.tipo_doc
END
```

Comment: Porque ejecutas el comando en una variable int?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás asignando como valor de los parámetros las referencias a los DropDownList, pero deberías pasarle el valor seleccionado.

Por ejemplo, deberías reemplazar esta linea:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@estado", SqlDbType.Int).Value = estado
```

por esta linea:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@estado", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Integer.Parse(estado.SelectedValue)
```

También deberías poner en la propiedad DataValueField de cada SqlDataSource el nombre del campo utilizado como clave, el cual se enviará como parámetro al stored procedure.
Lo mismo con el resto de los valores de los DropDownList.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Me genero este error "La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto."

Comment: Seguramente sea porque alguna opción del dropdown no tiene un número en el valor. ¿Puede ser?

Comment: que valor?, podría explicarme

Comment: El valor que viene del campo tipo_estado, que es el que se guarda como value de cada opción del dropdown.

Comment: O sea, en el DataValueField de ese SqlDataSource deberías poner el nombre del campo que utilices como clave primaria, el cual creo que debería ser del tipo int, ya que así lo estás asignado al parámetro @estado del stored procedure.